# ngx-mqtt service options error for protocol

Tags: angular, mqtt

In my application i am using angular 7 and the ngx-mqtt package "ngx-mqtt": "^6.8.3". The application works over https so secure connection is used on MQTT server too.

this is my environment.ts

```
MQTTCONFIG: {
    broker: 'theBroker',
    hostname: 'theHostname',
    **protocol: 'wss'**,
    port: thePort,
    username: 'theUsername',
    password: 'thePassword',
    path: 'thePath',
    topic_query: 'theTopicQuery',
    topic_update_state: 'theTopicUpdateState',
    clientID: 'smartorder'
  }
```

and this is my app.module.ts (some declarations and imports are omitted):

```
import { MqttMessage, MqttModule, MqttServiceOptions } from 'ngx-mqtt';
.
.
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MaterialModule,
    LayoutModule,
    MqttModule.forRoot(environment.MQTTCONFIG)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I am getting the following error though:

```
ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(62,24): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ broker: string; hostname: string; protocol: string; port: number; username: string; password: string; path: string; topic_query: string; topic_update_state: string; clientID: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IMqttServiceOptions'.
  Types of property 'protocol' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"wss" | "ws"'.
```

Line 62 is this: MqttModule.forRoot(environment.MQTTCONFIG)

Property protocol in the MQTT options is set to 'wss':
**protocol: 'wss'**

How can I correct this error?

Comment: I am getting a CERT_ERROR while making a connection like above. Can someone suggest how can we send CERT details with ngx-mqtt.

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari this is probably has to do with CORS. Υou can find a plugin for your browser that disables it

Answer (score 0):

The ngx-mqtt library you are using takes a enumeration for the protocol. Unfortunetally, you can not set enumeration values in your environment.ts without the typings.

simple workaround:
exclude the protocol value from the environment.ts and set it directly in your app.module.ts like so:

```
// environment.ts
MQTTCONFIG: {
    broker: 'theBroker',
    hostname: 'theHostname',
    port: thePort,
    username: 'theUsername',
    password: 'thePassword',
    path: 'thePath',
    topic_query: 'theTopicQuery',
    topic_update_state: 'theTopicUpdateState',
    clientID: 'smartorder'
}
```

and

```
// app.module.ts
export const MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS: IMqttServiceOptions = {
    broker: environment.MQTTCONFIG.broker,
    connectOnCreate: true,
    hostname: environment.MQTTCONFIG.hostname,
    port: environment.MQTTCONFIG.port,
    path: environment.MQTTCONFIG.path,
    username: environment.MQTTCONFIG.username,
    password: environment.MQTTCONFIG.password,
    topic_query: environment.MQTTCONFIG.topic_query,
    topic_update_state: environment.MQTTCONFIG.topic_update_state,
    clientID: environment.MQTTCONFIG.clientID,
    protocol: 'wss'
};
```

If you really want to use the protocol from your environment.ts, then set `connectOnCreate: false`, load the protocol from inside your app controller **after** build when you have the missing typings available and then connect to the broker.

Comment: thanks for the workaround. I just set the protocol variable to string the library and the validation was successful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typescript error, you have to narrow down the type from `string` to `'ws' | 'wss'`. Ideally you don't want to redefine hardcoded enum types so you can piggyback on the existing definition as such:

```
{
  ...
  protocol: 'wss' as IMqttServiceOptions['protocol'],
  ...
}
```